# How do I Bevel an Edge within an Edge?

Tags: modeling, edges, bevel

[image: **enter image description here**]

Edit Update:

I want to explain how I got to this point better because I did a poor job explaining, so here it is. I am making a box. Along one edge of the box I pressed "W" then "subdivide" to create a single vertice. After which I had selected the single vertice I created on its own, and then pressed 
"ctrl shift B" to create two vertices, when I had the desired distance I wanted I then switched to edge select, and selected the edge between the two vertices I created then pressed "ctrl B" which results in the image above. I have no doubles, and using "ctrl A" in object mode doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: could you please share your file with the problem? it's not clear what's the problem

Comment: Can you check you don't have doubles? Try remove doubles please.

Comment: I tried remove doubles with no luck the issue persists. I changed my description to better explain my problem. I'll try to upload the file if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have enough rep points to comment, but, to comment, I did what you wanted, just with CTRL+B, not sure where the problems is with your bevel. Maybe, CTRL+A first ? scale / rotation / location....

OP edit: SpaceKat had recommended resetting my settings. Which I did by reinstalling the latest version of Blender 2.79B, the original version I used was 2.78. Using the newer version of Blender fixed the issue right away no problems at all. I wanted to give SpaceKat proper credit so I edited the post.

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me. I must have messed up some setting because I tried again with a new cube and am still having the same issue. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Maybe load start up file and save as different setting if can - reset blender possibly - oh and, after CTRL+A, you must go to edit mode to re-calculate outside, on some occasions,as it turns the faces around, but you will notice if this happens.

Comment: I think I tried your method properly. Going into object mode with the whole mesh selected then pressing "ctrl A" and I selected every option no luck. I would rather not reset my setting because I like where they are, and bevel works in every other instance. it did turn the faces of the bevel from instead of being aligned with the Z axis the faces are now aligned with the X. I tried this with a fresh starter file same issue again.